# Show that $\frac1n\max\limits_{1\le i \le n } X_i\to0$ almost surely, with no independence assumption

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, self-learning

This is self-study, I encountered this problem in one of the previous examination papers.

> Let $X_1,X_2,\dots $ be a sequence of identically distributed random variables with $E|X_1| < \infty $ and let $Y_n = \frac1n\max_{1 \le i \le n } X_i$. Show that $Y_n \overset{a.s.}{\to} 0$

This problem is fairly straightforward if it was i.i.d case - one can easily find the distribution of sample maximum and use Borel Cantelli lemma 1 to show that this almost surely happens.

Because this is an examination question, I think, one clue is to use Markov's inequality because of the $E[|X|]$ term.

Any clues are greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a first step, can you show that $P(Y_n>y)\to0$ for every $y>0$?

Comment: @Did: Actually, I am unable to. Here is my attempt: Assuming $X_j$ is the maximum of the lot, $P(Y_n > y) = P(|X_j| > ny) = 1- P(\underset{\forall 1 \le i  \neq j \le n } {|X_n| < ny})$ I am not sure how to proceed further. If it was iid, it would have been straightforward.

Comment: Not sure I am following the identity in your comment... You might want to use the relation $[Y_n>y]=\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n[|X_k|>ny]$.

Comment: @Did: $P[Y_n>y]=\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^nP[|X_k|>ny] \le \sum_{k=1}^nP[|X_k|>ny] \le \frac{E[|X|]}{y}$ But still cannot show that $P(Y_n>y)\to0$

Comment: Any other idea to show that $nP(|X_1|>ny)\to0$? Note that $nyP(|X_1|>ny)=E(ny\mathbf 1_{|X_1|>ny})\leqslant E(|X_1|\mathbf 1_{|X_1|>ny})$...

Comment: @Did: I will try this new line of thought. On a side note, I did not remember the remember the proof of Markov's inequality. Thanks for making me intuitively derive it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82270/discussion-between-kasa-and-did).

Comment: @kasa This is a good question and I am waiting for an answer.. If you get a proof with help from Did please  post the answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Sure, sir. I am waiting for my professor to discuss it. I found the exact same question here. But I am not convinced of the answer though. It would be great if domain experts such as yours can discuss this answer in a simple and understable way. . https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994190/suppose-that-x-i-are-independent-random-variables-with-finite-absolute-moment?rq=1

Comment: @kasa Thanks for the reference. I got the proof from that post.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Could please explain why $\sum_n  Y \Pr \{2^n\leqslant Y \lt 2^{n +1}  \}$ is finite in that proof? Probably, I am too naive to see it. Also, is it important to deal in terms of $2^n$ in that answer?

Comment: @kasa $EY \geq \sum \int_{\{2^{n} leq Y <2^{n+1}\}} Y \geq \sum 2^{n} P\{{2^{n} leq Y <2^{n+1}\}$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Thank you, sir. 
For others, $ EY \geq \sum \int_{\{2^{n} \leq Y <2^{n+1}\}} Y \geq \sum 2^{n} P\{{2^{n} \leq Y <2^{n+1}\}}$ is the clue

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy See below for a different proof.

Comment: @Shalop Thank you very much. We were all making a mountain out of a mole hill!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an easy argument.

Wlog assume $X_n\geq 0$ (else replace $X_n$ with $|X_n|$ throughout the proof below).

First note that $X_n/n \to 0$ almost surely, by Borel-Cantelli and the fact that for any $\epsilon>0$ one has $$\sum_n \Bbb P(X_n\geq\epsilon n) = \sum \Bbb P(X_1\geq \epsilon n) =\Bbb E\bigg[ \sum 1_{\{X_1\geq\epsilon n\}} \bigg] \leq 1+\epsilon^{-1}\Bbb E|X_1|.$$

Now if $x_n$ is any (deterministic) sequence of non-negative real numbers such that $x_n/n \to 0$, then it is true that $\frac1n \max_{1\leq i \leq n} x_i \to 0.$ Indeed, this can be proved by noting that for any $N \leq n$ one has $\frac1n \max_{1\leq i \leq n} x_i \leq \frac{1}{n} \max_{1\leq i \leq N} x_i +\max_{N < i \leq n} \frac{x_i}{i}$. Now it's just an elementary real-analysis argument (I leave the details to you).

Independence is not needed.

Comment: Sorry, there was an error (now fixed) where I forgot an $\epsilon$ there. The terms of that infinite sum inside the expectation are equal to $1$ for $n = 0,1,2,..., \lfloor X_1/\epsilon\rfloor$. Then they are zero for all larger $n$. Hence the sum is just equal to one plus the floor of $X_1/\epsilon$.

Comment: Can you please check this.  Here is my attempt for finishing off the proof: $\sum_{n=1} \Bbb P (\max_{1 \leq i \leq n }  \frac{x_i}{n} > \epsilon )  \leq \sum_{n=1} \Bbb P (\max_{1 \leq i \leq n  }\frac{x_i}{i} > \epsilon)$ is finite.

Comment: @kasa no, there should be no probability involved in this part of the argument. Maybe you're confusing this epsilon with the one from before, so I changed the wording.

Comment: I am ashamed to ask this. Could you please complete the remaining steps too? I am unable to figure it out despite spending a decent amount of time. Thank you

Comment: Ya no problem! Let $a_n:=\frac1n \max_{1 \le i \le n} x_i $. In order to show that $a_n \to 0$, we need to show (by definition of convergence) that for any $\delta>0$ there exists some $A \in \Bbb N$ such that $n \geq A$ implies $a_n \leq \delta$. So we know that for $N \leq n$, $$a_n \leq \frac1n \max_{1 \leq i \leq N} x_i + \max_{N < i \leq n} \frac{x_i}{i}.$$ Knowing this, we choose $N=N(\delta)$ large enough so that $x_i/i<\delta/2$ whenever $i>N$. We can do this since $x_i/i \to 0$. Next we choose $A=A(\delta)$ large enough so that...

Comment: ... $\frac{1}{n} \max_{1 \leq i \leq N(\delta)} x_i < \delta/2$ whenever $n \geq A$. Then we just combine the previous two estimates and we are done. Specifically, we get $a_n < \delta/2+\delta/2 = \delta$ for $n \geq A$, as desired.