# If $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ converges a.s. to a finite constant, then $E|X_n|<+\infty$.

Tags: probability-theory

The complete question is:

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be an I.I.D. random variable sequence. If $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ converges to a finite constant, then $X_n$ is integrable.

It seems like the inverse problem of Strong Law of Large Numbers. But it really gets me stuck.

Note: I have seen some similar problem at here: [Convergence of the empirical average of iid random variables in probability implies integrability](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2299822/759535)
, where it assumes that $X_i$ is non-negative.

Try: Thanks to Murthy, I have discovered something new:

1. We can write $X_i$ as $X_i = X_i^+ - X_i^-$, where $X_i^+ = X_i\cdot 1_{X_i>0}$ and $X_i^- = X_i\cdot 1_{X_i<0}$, then $$E|X_i|<+\infty \iff E|X_i^+|<+\infty , E|X_i^-|<+\infty$$
2. We assume that $E|X_n| = \infty$, then $E|X_n^+| = \infty$ or $E|X_n^-| = \infty$ or they both become infinite.
3. For first two cases, we can use the method [THAT LINK](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2299822/759535) mentioned. But it can not be used in the third case.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Sorry, I have edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S_n = \sum_{j=1}^n X_j$.

Let $A$ be the event $\{|X_n|>n\mbox{ i.o.}\}$. By the two Borel-Cantelli lemmas $P(A)=0$ or $P(A)=1$ according to whether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X_1|>n)$ converges or not.

Note that the convergence of the series is equivalent to  $E[|X_1|]<\infty$, because $E[|X_1|]=  \int_0^\infty P(|X_1|>t) dt$.

Now $\frac{S_{n+1}}{n+1}= \frac{n}{n+1}\frac{S_n}{n}+\frac{X_{n+1}}{n+1}$ and therefore

$$\frac{S_{n+1} }{n+1} - \frac{S_n}{n} = \frac{X_{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1} \frac{S_n}{n}.$$

The LHS converges to $0$ a.s. by assumption. Therefore the RHS too. As by assumption the second summand in the RHS tends to zero a.s., it follows that  $X_{n+1}/(n+1)\to 0$ a.s. and so $P(A)=0$. Therefore $E[|X_1|]<\infty$.

In fact, a [stronger result holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994190/suppose-that-x-i-are-independent-random-variables-with-finite-absolute-moment?rq=1).

Comment: Really impressive method! Thank you!